# Generator Function for inOrder traversal

Tags: python, generator

I've been working on my generator functions and expressions recently, but I'm not quite sure how I would tackle this. How could I use a generator function to yield and then later print the values in order?

I built my BST using pythons list

```
bst = [20, [10, [5, [2, [], []], [8, [], []]], [15, [], []]], [30, [25, [22, [], []], [27, [], []]], [35, [], [37, [], []]]]]
```

If I were to print the inorder traversal, I have no problem. So if I were to call `inorder(bst)` for the following function:

```
def inorder(tree):
    if tree:
        inorder(tree[1])
        print (tree[0])
        inorder(tree[2])
```

I get this output.

```
2
5
8
10
15
20
22
25
27
30
35
37
```

I would think that a generator expression would be equally as simple

```
def inorder(tree):
    if tree:
        inorder(tree[1])
        yield (tree[0])
        inorder(tree[2])
```

The problem I'm running into is getting my main to iterate through what's yielded in the function. I thought it was supposed to be something like

```
test= inorder(bst)

for i in range(0,len(l)): # l is the number of items in bst
    print (next(test))
```

Instead of iterating over the entire functions yields, it simply stops the iterable seemingly before it starts.

```
    20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functionGenerator.py", line 64, in <module>
    print(next(test))
StopIteration
```

What do I need to do to make my function generator operate correctly?

Comment: Your syntax error has nothing to do with generators, you are using Python 2 syntax in Python 3.

Comment: Alright, what would python 3 syntax look like instead?

Comment: `print(next(test))`

Comment: You are using it in your original `inorder()` implementation...

Comment: Your recursive `inorder()` has other issues however; you need to use `yield from inorder(tree[1])` or `for res in inorder(tree[1]): yield res`.

Comment: Thank you for post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters , where in `inorder()` would you put it? I have tried your method and yet my 'Stop Iteration' before I even print the first value. I don't understand why the yielding of the value would be any different than the printing of the value.

Comment: Start with providing a proper [mcve] and give us input data and expected output results.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I gave all the code one would need to run in python, as well as inputs and expected results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `inorder()` implementation doesn't correctly recurse. You are only printing the current top node of your tree. That's because only calling `inorder(tree[1])` or `inorder(tree[2])` returns a generator object, you are not iterating over those generators.

Use

```
def inorder(tree):
    if tree:
        yield from inorder(tree[1])
        yield tree[0]
        yield from inorder(tree[2])
```

The [`yield from` expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) delegates the generator to another, yielding from that sub-generator until it is done. That way you properly recurse.

If you are using an older Python release (before Python 3.3), you need to manually iterate over the recursive calls:

```
def inorder(tree):
    if tree:
        for sub in inorder(tree[1]):
            yield sub
        yield tree[0]
        for sub in inorder(tree[2]):
            yield sub
```

Next, you can just iterate over the `inorder()` generator:

```
>>> for node in inorder(bst):
...     print(node)
...
2
5
8
10
15
20
22
25
27
30
35
37
```

although using `next()` works too:

```
>>> tree = inorder(bst)
>>> print(next(tree))
2
>>> print(next(tree))
5
```

but iteration is cleaner and stops automatically once `StopIteration` is raised.

Comment: Thank you, I will make sure to follow the minimal complete and verifiable example in future questions.